# Tomcat - Jersey - Swagger.Json not getting generated

Tags: swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I want to generate Swagger API documentation for ReST service developed using Jersey.

I have gone through Swagger API documentation and deployed as per the documentation.

But i am getting the following output when i access the URL (http://localhost:8080/MySwagger/swagger.json).

```
{

"swagger" : "2.0",

  "info" : 
   {

    "version" : "1.0.2",

    "title" : "UUK"
  },

  "host" : "localhost:8080",

  "basePath" : "/MySwagger",

  "schemes" : [ "http" ]

}
```

The above one deosn't contain API that we have developed

I have tried the various options mentioned in the documentation but the result is same.

I have deployed the application in tomcat 7.0.68.

My Java version is 7

I have used maven to download the dependency Jars and **manually** copy the Jars to /WEB-INF/lib directory

## Maven Script

```
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=io.swagger -DartifactId=swagger-jersey2-jaxrs -Dversion=1.5.7
```

## My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers,
                test.EventReceiver
            </param-value>
        </init-param>       

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.bootstrap.SwaggerApplication</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

## **My Custom Servlet Class**

```
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class SwaggerApplication extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
    {
    super.init(config);

    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath(config.getServletContext().getContextPath());
    beanConfig.setTitle("UUK");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
    }
}
```

## My API Class

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path(value="/v1/")
@Api(value="inboundtransaction" ,description = "Receive Inbound transaction", position = 1, protocols = "http")

public class EventReceiver 
{
    @POST
    @Path(value="/inboundtransaction")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

    @ApiOperation(value="Receiving Inbound transaction from X", notes = "Must Contain ID",httpMethod = "POST",response=String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = 
    { 
              @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Received request and process later", response=String.class),
              @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Server Busy. Please re-send later", response=String.class) 
    }
    )

    public String inboundtransaction(
            @ApiParam(value = "Pass mandatory values to create EdiAddress",required = true) String data
            ) 
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue in the current setup.

Regards

Udhaya

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your package , it is a string with comma sepearated packages.

beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources, , ");